# Issue Making Blocked Divs

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I just started a basic MVC 4 application and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to make two divs appear in blocks instead of next to each other. In my `_Layout.cshtml` file, I have the following code for the `body` tag:

```
<body>
    <div style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; display: block">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="headerImage" style="height: 200px; width: 150px; float: left"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="body" style="display: block">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

And the `headerImage` class:

```
.headerImage
 {
     background: url('@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/foo.jpg")');
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-size:100%;
 }
```

Now in my `Index.cshtml` view, which gets rendered as part of `@RenderBody()`, I have a simple button:

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller"))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="hello world" />
    }
</div>
```

When I run this, the button is placed right next to the image, even though they are in different divs:

[image]

I even tried setting `display:block` on the divs but that didn't help either. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `#body { clear: both; }` to get that to display under the image?

Comment: That did it. Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Just added an answer below, with a link to more information on clearing floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to clear your second `<div>`, as follows:

```
#body {
    clear: both;
}
```

More information on clearing your floats can be found at [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clear/)